# How to connect react web part to azure sql database?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, azure, react-webpart

Any advice about how to connect a spfx web part using the react template to an azure sql database.

But can't seem to find a clear example. I'd be looking to bind controls e.g. Combo boxes  to a sql azure sql table

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remember that anything that runs client side is able to be sniffed out by the end user, so any front end code connecting to a database would necessarily expose the connection details back to the end user - the keys to the kingdom, if you will. This is an egregious security risk.

Best practice is to deploy a custom secured web service, and have the web part call that instead.

There's a lot of ways to achieve this, but very common is to use Azure Functions and/or ASP.Net secured with Azure Active Directory: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-api-secured-with-aad

Comment: Thanks I will give it a go. Can it also be done using node?

Comment: Google says yes: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/node-js-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017